# puttygen pub key to git ssh keys

Tags: git, ssh, putty

When generating key pair with gitbash `ssh-keygen`, public key file content looks like

```
ssh-rsa AAA...== myemail@exmaple.com
```

which is successfully imported to git ssh keys, but private key can't be used with pageant.

When generating key pair with `PuTTYgen`, public key file content looks like

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "rsa-key-20171213"
AA...==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

which can't be imported to git ssh key, because of expected format, but private key can be used with pageant.

**Is there a way of generating keypair with either tool (`ssh-keygen` or `PuTTYgen`) to work on both ends (`git` and `pageant`) from the get go, without altering file content?**

Answer (score 2):

Actually PuTTYgen does provide OpenSSH format when keys are generated

[image]

However saving public key does the other thing. So whenever OpenSSH format is needed, private key can be loaded in PuTTYgen and copied from there.

Answer (score 0):

ssh-keygen generates keys in OpenSSH format. Putty generates keys in Putty private key (ppk) format. This [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74545/what-difference-between-openssh-key-and-putty-key#74628) should be useful for you.

PuttyGen is capable of converting ppk to OpenSSH format and vica versa, but only the private one.

Edit: see comments

Comment: thanks for pointing out OpenSSH format, but conversion only saves private key

Comment: You are right, thanks for the correction.